# Does WebGL matrix (mat4) notation corresponds to mathematical matrix notation

Tags: javascript, matrix, opengl-es, webgl, shader

Documentation for [The OpenGL ES Shading Language](https://www.khronos.org/files/opengles_shading_language.pdf) (section 5.11) states that vector and matrix multiplcation operations performs in the correct linear algebraic way.
Linear algebra teaches if we multiply matrix by vector we get such result:

```
1.0 1.0 0.0   -1.0   (1.0*-1.0)+(1.0*0.0)+(0.0*0.0)=-1.0
0.5 0.0 0.0 *  0.0 = (0.5*-1.0)+(0.0*0.0)+(0.0*0.0)=-0.5
0.0 0.0 0.0    0.0   (0.0*-1.0)+(0.0*0.0)+(0.0*0.0)= 0.0

1.0 1.0 0.0    0.0    1.0
0.5 0.0 0.0 *  1.0 =  0.0
0.0 0.0 0.0    0.0    0.0

1.0 1.0 0.0    1.0    1.0
0.5 0.0 0.0 *  0.0 =  0.5
0.0 0.0 0.0    0.0    0.0
```

But when I use this mathematical knowledge for multiplication matrix by vector in WebGL vertex-shader I face with problem.
When I try multiply analogue of above matrix:

```
mat4 matrix=mat4(
1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
```

to three verticles: red(x=-1,y=0,z=0,w=1), green(x=0,y=1,z=0,w=1), blue(x=1,y=0,z=0,w=1) of simplest isosceles triangle I get strange practical coordinates: red(-1,-1,0,1), green(0.5,0,0,1), blue(1,1,0,1), instead of the expected from above theoretical calculations: red(-1,-0.5,0,1), green(1,0,0,1), blue(1,0.5,0,1). Source code that demonstrates problem is [avaliable here](http://acadyt.scienceontheweb.net/webgl_multiplication.htm).

These strange coordinates will be matematically correct only if assume that mat4 matrix was auto-transposed before multiplication (documentation for The OpenGL ES Shading Language states that OpenGL stores matrix data in column major order: may be this is the reason?).

So, the question, does WebGL notation

```
mat4 matrix=mat4(
1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
```

mean in mathematical sense such matrix as:

```
1.0 0.5 0.0 0.0
1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0
0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0
```

or not? Should I believe my eyes or documentation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> So, the question, does WebGL notation .... mean in mathematical sense such matrix as .... or not?

Yes, it means.

What you actually initialize is a transposed matrix, compared to what you expected. Either you have to change the matrix initialization or you have to multiply the vector to the matrix from the left.

**Explanation**

See [The OpenGL ES Shading Language, 5.4.2 Vector and Matrix Constructors, page 43](https://www.khronos.org/files/opengles_shading_language.pdf):

> To initialize a matrix by specifying vectors, or by all 4, 9, or 16 floats for `mat2`, `mat3` and `mat4` respectively. The floats are assigned to elements in **column major** order.
>
> ```
> mat2(vec2, vec2);
> mat3(vec3, vec3, vec3);
> mat4(vec4, vec4, vec4, vec4);
>
> mat2(float, float,
>      float, float);
>
> mat3(float, float, float,
>      float, float, float,
>      float, float, float);
>
> mat4(float, float, float, float,
>      float, float, float, float,
>      float, float, float, float,
>      float, float, float, float);
> ```

This means, the following initialization of a `mat4`

```
mat4 matrix=mat4(
    1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
```

corresponds to the following mathematical matrix:

```
  c0  c1  c2  c3             c0   c1   c2   c3
[ Xx  Yx  Zx  Tx ]        [ 1.0  0.5  0.0  0.0 ]     
[ Xy  Yy  Zy  Ty ]        [ 1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0 ]     
[ Xz  Yz  Zz  Tz ]        [ 0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0 ]     
[  0   0   0   1 ]        [ 0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0 ]
```

But the memory image of the matrix is:

```
   Xx,  Xy,  Xz,   0,  Yx,  Yy,  Yz,   0,  Zx,  Zy,  Zz,   0,  Tx,  Ty,  Tz,   1
[ 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ]
```

See also [Data Type (GLSL) - Matrix constructors](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Data_Type_(GLSL)#Matrix_constructors)

> For matrices, construction is rather more complicated.
>
> If a matrix is constructed with a single scalar value, then that value is used to initialize all the values along the diagonal of the matrix; the rest are given zeros. Therefore, mat4(1.0) is a 4x4 identity matrix.
>
> For multiple values, matrices are filled in in column-major order. That is, **the first X values are the first column, the second X values are the next column**, and so forth. Examples:
>
> ```
> mat2(
>     float, float,   // first column
>     float, float);  // second column
> ```

---

The same is the case when accessing the fields of a matrix:

See [The OpenGL ES Shading Language, 5.6 Matrix Components, page 45](https://www.khronos.org/files/opengles_shading_language.pdf):

> The components of a matrix can be accessed using array subscripting syntax. Applying a single subscript to a matrix **treats the matrix as an array of column vectors**, and selects a single column, whose type is a vector of the same size as the matrix. The leftmost column is column 0. A second subscript would then operate on the column vector, as defined earlier for vectors. Hence, two subscripts select a column and then a row.
>
> ```
> mat4 m;
> m[1] = vec4(2.0); // sets the second column to all 2.0
> m[0][0] = 1.0; // sets the upper left element to 1.0
> m[2][3] = 2.0; // sets the 4th element of the third column to 2.0
> ```

---

Note, the multiplication of a vector and a matrix is defined as follows:

See [The OpenGL ES Shading Language, 5.11 Vector and Matrix Operations, page 50](https://www.khronos.org/files/opengles_shading_language.pdf):

> .... The exceptions are matrix multiplied by vector, vector multiplied by matrix, and matrix multiplied by matrix. These do not operate component-wise, but rather perform the correct linear algebraic multiply. They require the size of the operands match.
>
> ```
> vec3 v, u;
> mat3 m;
> ```
>
> `u = v * m;` is equivalent to
>
> ```
> u.x = dot(v, m[0]); // m[0] is the left column of m
> u.y = dot(v, m[1]); // dot(a,b) is the inner (dot) product of a and b
> u.z = dot(v, m[2]);
> ```
>
> And `u = m * v;` is equivalent to
>
> ```
> u.x = m[0].x * v.x + m[1].x * v.y + m[2].x * v.z;
> u.y = m[0].y * v.x + m[1].y * v.y + m[2].y * v.z;
> u.z = m[0].z * v.x + m[1].z * v.y + m[2].z * v.z;
> ```

Referring to the 1st example in the question, this means, the result of

```
mat4 m = mat4(
    1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

vec4 v = vec4( -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );

u = m * v
```

is:

```
u.x  = m[0].x * v.x  + m[1].x * v.y + m[2].x * v.z + m[3].x * v.w;
u.y  = m[0].y * v.x  + m[1].y * v.y + m[2].y * v.z + m[3].y * v.w;
u.z  = m[0].z * v.x  + m[1].z * v.y + m[2].z * v.z + m[3].z * v.w;
u.w  = m[0].w * v.x  + m[1].w * v.y + m[2].w * v.z + m[3].w * v.w;

u.x  =  1.0 * -1.0   +  0.5 * 0.0   +  0.0 * 0.0   +  0.0 * 1.0  =  -1.0
u.y  =  1.0 * -1.0   +  0.0 * 0.0   +  0.0 * 0.0   +  0.0 * 1.0  =  -1.0
u.z  =  0.0 * -1.0   +  0.0 * 0.0   +  1.0 * 0.0   +  0.0 * 1.0  =   0.0
u.w  =  0.0 * -1.0   +  0.0 * 0.0   +  0.0 * 0.0   +  1.0 * 1.0  =   1.0
```

But the result of `u_ = v * m` would be:

```
u_.x  =  dot(v, m[0]);
u_.y  =  dot(v, m[1]);
u_.z  =  dot(v, m[2]); 
u_.w  =  dot(v, m[3]); 

u_.x  =  dot( vec4( -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ), vec4( 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 ) )  =  -1.0 
u_.y  =  dot( vec4( -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ), vec4( 0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ) )  =  -0.5
u_.z  =  dot( vec4( -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ), vec4( 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 ) )  =   0.0
u_.w  =  dot( vec4( -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ), vec4( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ) )  =   1.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much for very exhaustive and detailed written answer! This completely eliminates my difficulties.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Great! But there is a mistake u.x  =  1.0 * -1.0   +  0.5 * 0.0   +  0.0 * 0.0   +  0.0 * 1.0  =  -0.5  results -1.0 and not -0.5

Comment: @Umbert Thank you very much! Good eyes!